# SQL Nested Exception

Tags: java, oracle11g

I am facing this problem.

**Stackstrace**

> 2014-09-22 16:50:35,292 [main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   - Could not obtain connection metadata org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset) at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)

can any one please let me know the cause of this , oracle version is 11g

Comment: What is occurring when you get this issue?

Comment: In the logs of my Process , when we start the process .

Comment: Post your class/xml file that shows your db configurations.

Comment: I see this is just a warning? Do you have any errors at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace specifies that you are unable to connect to your database.

- Make sure that your database server is listening on the correct port (1521 default).
- Check your firewall or any setting that prevents you from accessing your database server
- Check your dataSource settings for any errors.
- If your database is an external one, make sure that the listener.ora is configured correctly.